# Install Sample Data in Magento 2

Tags: magento, sample-data

I have tried a lot for install sample data in Magento 2. I am trying a new method, but still not getting success.

```
sudo php bin/magento sampledata:deploy
```

After apply this code i am getting this

```
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
    Authentication required (repo.magento.com):       
      Username:
```

I dont know which username and password is asking here. I have generate token in my magento account. But what to do next and which user name and password to give there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 2):

You get following message

*You are required to authenticate to complete the action.* when you try to upgrade or install the sample data in Magento 2 using Composer method using following command.

```
php <your Magento install dir>/bin/magento sampledata:deploy
```

This is a new concept in Magento 2 for upgrades. You have to configure your keys in you Magento account under connect tab *secure keys* section. (As you have to access a repository)

You will find following excerpt from Magento official documentation :

*The repo.magento.com repository, where Magento 2 and third-party component Composer packages are stored, requires authentication. To provide secure authentication, we enable you to generate a pair 32-character authentication tokens you can use to access the repository.*

Please refer this [Enter your authentication keys in the Admin](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/comp-mgr/prereq/prereq_auth-token.html)